# External Monitor flickering issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, dvi, docking-station

I have a Samsung S24E650 monitor. It is connected to my laptop or even docking station and it both options the screen flickers.
I am doing this connection using a dvi in to hdmi out cable.

The drivers are updated on my win10 laptop, the issue does not happen with my other Samsung S24B420 which is connected with the same cable.

I am not sure what else I could do regarding this issue. The monitor also has a DP iN input which I could use but I am sceptic that buying an DP IN to hdmi cable.

Did anyone experience something like this ? If so , How did you fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the same issue with another monitor and same pc and cable, and most likely your monitor is the culprit.

It could be the DVI port, so using DP could indeed silver the issue, but can also be other issue and that case using different cable won't help.

Based on the symptoms it's just impossible to tell what exactly is the issue. Buying another cable seems to be a cheap way starting to investigate.